# wrong output when testing a different input (finding a path)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, path, depth-first-search

For school i need to make an assignment. We have to find a path between 2 vertices. I have given my code below, i almost got it working, but i am stuck at one part.
this is the input:

```
1->5
1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5,
```

this is the correct output:

```
1->2->3->4->5
```

My program also gives the correct output when passing this input. However when passing the following input:

```
    1->4000000000
    1, 2, 3; 2, 2; 3, 4, 5; 4, 1, 2; 5, 5, 4000000000; 4000000000, 2
```

This should be the output:

```
     1->3->5->4000000000
```

but my program gives me this

```
     1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5-> 4000000000
```

How can i optimize this? Thanks for the help in advanve!

```
import sys
from typing import List

stack: []

def output():
    '''
    Will print the path stored in the `stack` global variable.
    You are free to modify it to be a parameter.
    '''
    #for id in stack[:-1]:
        #print(f'{id}->', end='')
    #try:
        #print(f'{stack[-1]}')
    #except IndexError:
        #pass
    return "->".join(stack) if stack else ""


def find_path(graph, start, target, path):
    #print(start, target)
    path = path + [start]
    #print(path)
    if start == target:
        return path
    for node in graph:
        #print(node)
        if node not in path: ##idk what to do here..
            new_path = find_path(graph, node, target, path)
            if new_path:
                return new_path
    return path

def add_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    if key not in dict_obj:
        dict_obj[key] = list()
    dict_obj[key].append(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    Fetch starting and target nodes.
    '''
    start, target = [x for x in input().split('->')]
    #print(start, target)
    '''
    Fetch `;` separated twitter data. <id-1: u_int>, <following: u_int>, ..<following: u_int>; ... 
    i.e: 1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5,
    '''
    data = input()
    data_l: List = data.split(';')
    graph = dict()
    for d in data_l:
        id, followers = d.split(', ', 1)
        # print(followers)
        following_l: List = followers.split(', ')
        for f in following_l:
            if f == '':
                # node is not following other nodes.
                continue
        add_value(graph, id, followers)
    print(graph)
    stack = find_path(graph, start, target, [])

sys.stdout.write(output())
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Yes i tried, but idk where the mistake in the code is located. That's why i posted my question here. Currently i still am trying to fix it!

Comment: put many `print()` in all code and compare steps from code with steps made on paper.

Comment: shorter: `start, target = input().split('->')`

Comment: first mistake is how you create `graph`, you add `followers` but it is string like `"1, 2"`  - you should add `following_l` which is a list `["1", "2"]`

Comment: another mistake: you use `for node in graph:` but you should use `graph[start]` in `for node in graph[start]:`

Comment: asnother mistake: you shouldn't add `start` to `path` becaus it may not be correct direction. You should add it `visited`. and later check `if node not in visited`. And when you `new_path` will be not empty then you should `return [start] + new_path`. And when it can't find path then you should return empty list, not `path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake: you add `followers` which is string like `"1, 2"` - you should add `following_l` which is a list `["1", "2"]`

Another mistake: you use `for node in graph:` but you should use `graph[start]` in `for node in graph[start]:`

Another mistake: you shouldn't add `start` to `path` because it may not be correct direction - but you should add it when you find `new_path` - `return [start] + new_path`.

And when it can't find path then you should return empty list, not path

You should add `start` to separated list `visited` and later check `if node not in visited`  - to check every node only once.

```
def find_path(graph, start, target):
    print('find_path:', start, '->', target)

    visited.append(start)
    
    if start == target:
        return [start]
    
    for node in graph[start]:
        #print('node:', node)
        if node not in visited:
            path = find_path(graph, node, target)
            if path:
                print('path:', [start] + path)
                return [start] + path
                
    return []
```

---

My full version:

```
def find_path(graph, start, target, visited):
    print('find_path:', start, '->', target)

    visited.append(start)
    
    if start == target:
        return [start]
    
    for node in graph[start]:
        #print('node:', node)
        if node not in visited:
            path = find_path(graph, node, target, visited)
            if path:
                print('path:', [start] + path)
                return [start] + path
                
    return []

def main(path, data):
    start, target = path.split('->')
    print('start, target:', start, target)

    data = data.split(';')

    graph = dict()
    
    for d in data:
        parts = d.split(',')
        
        if len(parts) > 1:
            id = parts[0]
            id = id.strip()
            
            followers = parts[1:]
            followers = [x.strip() for x in followers if x.strip()]
            
            print(id, 'followers:', followers)

            if followers:
                graph[id] = followers

    print('graph:', graph)
    
    visited = list()
    stack = find_path(graph, start, target, visited)

    output = "->".join(stack)
    
    print('output:', output)
    
    print('------')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #path = input()
    #data = input()
    #main(path, data)
    
    path = '1->4000000000'
    data = '1, 2, 3; 2, 2; 3, 4, 5; 4, 1, 2; 5, 5, 4000000000; 4000000000, 2'
    main(path, data)

    path = '1->5'
    data = '1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5,'
    main(path, data)
```

Result:

```
start, target: 1 4000000000
1 followers: ['2', '3']
2 followers: ['2']
3 followers: ['4', '5']
4 followers: ['1', '2']
5 followers: ['5', '4000000000']
4000000000 followers: ['2']
graph: {'1': ['2', '3'], '2': ['2'], '3': ['4', '5'], '4': ['1', '2'], '5': ['5', '4000000000'], '4000000000': ['2']}
find_path: 1 -> 4000000000
find_path: 2 -> 4000000000
find_path: 3 -> 4000000000
find_path: 4 -> 4000000000
find_path: 5 -> 4000000000
find_path: 4000000000 -> 4000000000
path: ['5', '4000000000']
path: ['3', '5', '4000000000']
path: ['1', '3', '5', '4000000000']
output: 1->3->5->4000000000
------
start, target: 1 5
1 followers: ['2']
2 followers: ['3']
3 followers: ['4']
4 followers: ['5']
5 followers: []
graph: {'1': ['2'], '2': ['3'], '3': ['4'], '4': ['5']}
find_path: 1 -> 5
find_path: 2 -> 5
find_path: 3 -> 5
find_path: 4 -> 5
find_path: 5 -> 5
path: ['4', '5']
path: ['3', '4', '5']
path: ['2', '3', '4', '5']
path: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
output: 1->2->3->4->5
------
```